# Shell script to check if file exists

Tags: shell

I'm trying to write a simple script that will tell me if a filename exist in $Temp that starts with the string "Test".

For example, I have these files

```
Test1989.txt
Test1990.txt
Test1991.txt
```

Then I just want to echo that a file was found.

For example, something like this:

```
file="home/edward/bank1/fiche/Test*"
if  test -s "$file" 
then 
    echo "found one"
else 
    echo "found none"
fi
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: The question specifies "shell" -- which one? The answer I consider best here is bash-specific; is that appropriate, or are you targeting something else?

Answer (score 9):

One approach:

```
(
  shopt -s nullglob
  files=(/home/edward/bank1/fiche/Test*)
  if [[ "${#files[@]}" -gt 0 ]] ; then
    echo found one
  else
    echo found none
  fi
)
```

Explanation:

- `shopt -s nullglob` will cause `/home/edward/bank1/fiche/Test*` to expand to *nothing* if no file matches that pattern. (Without it, it will be left intact.)
- `( ... )` sets up a subshell, preventing `shopt -s nullglob` from "escaping".
- `files=(/home/edward/bank1/fiche/Test*)` puts the file-list in an array named `files`. (Note that this is within the subshell only; `files` will not be accessible after the subshell exits.)
- `"${#files[@]}"` is the number of elements in this array.

---

**Edited to address** subsequent question ("What if i also need to check that these files have data in them and are not zero byte files"):

For this version, we need to use `-s` (as you did in your question), which also tests for the file's existence, so there's no point using `shopt -s nullglob` anymore: if no file matches the pattern, then `-s` on the pattern will be false. So, we can write:

```
(
  found_nonempty=''
  for file in /home/edward/bank1/fiche/Test* ; do
    if [[ -s "$file" ]] ; then
      found_nonempty=1
    fi
  done
  if [[ "$found_nonempty" ]] ; then
    echo found one
  else
    echo found none
  fi
)
```

(Here the `( ... )` is to prevent `file` and `found_file` from "escaping".)

Comment: What if i also need to check that these files have data in them and are not zero byte files

Comment: Then you need to write a loop like `for file in "${files[@]}"`

Comment: This is a great answer, and I've +1'd it -- my only quibble is that the use of a subshell is unnecessary, and it doesn't necessarily make sense to encourage an unnecessary `fork()`. If the goal is to avoid polluting global namespace, creating a function and using locals would suffice.

Answer (score 7):

You have to understand how Unix *interprets* your input.

The standard Unix shell interpolates environment variables, and what are called *globs* before it passes the parameters to your program. This is a bit different from Windows which makes the program interpret the expansion.

Try this:

```
 $ echo *
```

This will echo all the files and directories in your current directory. Before the `echo` command acts, the shell interpolates the `*` and expands it, then passes that expanded parameter back to your command. You can see it in action by doing this:

```
$ set -xv
$ echo *
$ set +xv
```

The `set -xv` turns on *xtrace* and *verbose*. Verbose echoes the command as entered, and *xtrace* echos the command that will be executed (that is, after the shell expansion).

Now try this:

```
$ echo "*"
```

Note that putting something inside quotes hides the *glob expression* from the shell, and the shell cannot expand it. Try this:

```
$ foo="this is the value of foo"
$ echo $foo
$ echo "$foo"
$ echo '$foo'
```

Note that the shell can still expand environment variables inside double quotes, but not in single quotes.

Now let's look at your statement:

```
file="home/edward/bank1/fiche/Test*"
```

The double quotes prevent the shell from expanding the *glob expression*, so `file` is equal to the literal `home/edward/bank1/finche/Test*`. Therefore, you need to do this:

```
file=/home/edward/bank1/fiche/Test*
```

The lack of quotes (and the introductory slash which is important!) will now make file equal to all files that match that expression. (There might be more than one!). If there are no files, depending upon the shell, and its settings, the shell may simply set file to that literal string anyway.

You certainly have the right idea:

```
 file=/home/edward/bank1/fiche/Test*
 if  test -s $file
    then 
        echo "found one"
    else 
       echo "found none"
 fi
```

However, you still might get *found none* returned if there is more than one file. Instead, you might get an error in your `test` command because there are too many parameters.

One way to get around this might be:

```
if ls /home/edward/bank1/finche/Test* > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "There is at least one match (maybe more)!"
else
    echo "No files found"
fi
```

In this case, I'm taking advantage of the exit code of the `ls` command. If `ls` finds one file it can access, it returns a zero exit code. If it can't find one matching file, it returns a non-zero exit code. The `if` command merely executes a command, and then if the command returns a zero, it assumes the `if` statement as *true* and executes the `if` clause. If the command returns a non-zero value, the `if` statement is assumed to be false, and the `else` clause (if one is available) is executed.

The `test` command works in a similar fashion. If the `test` is true, the `test` command returns a zero. Otherwise, the `test` command returns a non-zero value. This works great with the `if` command. In fact, there's an *alias* to the `test` command. Try this:

```
 $ ls -li /bin/test /bin/[
```

The `i` prints out the *inode*. The *inode* is the real ID of the file. Files with the same ID are the same file. You can see that `/bin/test` and `/bin/[` are the same command. This makes the following two commands the same:

```
if test -s $file
then
    echo "The file exists"
fi

if [ -s $file ]
then
    echo "The file exists"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one line:

```
ls /home/edward/bank1/fiche/Test* >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "found one" || echo "found none"
```

To understand what it does you have to decompose the command and have a basic awareness of boolean logic.

Directly from bash man page:

```
[...]
expression1 && expression2
     True if both expression1 and expression2 are true.
expression1 || expression2
     True if either expression1 or expression2 is true.
[...]
```

In the shell (and in general in unix world), the boolean true is a program that exits with status 0.

`ls` tries to list the pattern, if it succeed (meaning the pattern exists) it exits with status 0, 2 otherwise (have a look at ls man page for details).

In our case there are actually 3 expressions, for the sake of clarity I will put parenthesis, although they are not needed because `&&` has precedence on `||`:

```
 (expression1 && expression2) || expression3
```

so if expression1 is true (ie: `ls` found the pattern) it evaluates expression2 (which is just an echo and will exit with status 0). In this case expression3 is never evaluate because what's on the left site of `||` is already true and it would be a waste of resources trying to evaluate what's on the right.

Otherwise, if expression1 is false, expression2 is not evaluated but in this case expression3 is.

Comment: This is unnecessarily expensive. `ls` is an external program rather than a shell built-in, so invoking it forks. The shell can check for files without invoking _any_ external programs -- glob expressions, after all, do that. Also, `ls` spends time and CPU sorting its arguments, printing them (even if only to `/dev/null`); etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
for entry in "/home/loc/etc/"/*
do

   if [ -s /home/loc/etc/$entry ]
   then
       echo "$entry File is available"
   else
       echo "$entry File is not available"
fi
done

Hope it helps
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script will help u to go to a process if that script exist in a specified variable,

```
cat > waitfor.csh

    #!/bin/csh

    while !( -e $1 )

    sleep 10m

    end

ctrl+D
```

here `-e` is for working with files,

`$1` is a shell variable,

sleep for 10 minutes

u can execute the script by `./waitfor.csh ./temp ; echo "the file exits"`

Answer (score 0):

One liner to check file exist or not -

```
awk 'BEGIN {print getline < "file.txt" < 0 ? "File does not exist" : "File Exists"}'
```

Comment: OP needed to check for a file with a given name pattern in a particular directory and he needed it to be non-empty.

Answer (score -1):

Wildcards aren't expanded inside quoted strings. And when wildcard is expanded, it's returned unchanged if there are no matches, it doesn't expand into an empty string. Try:

```
output="$(ls home/edward/bank1/fiche/Test* 2>/dev/null)"
if [ -n "$output" ]
then echo "Found one"
else echo "Found none"
fi
```

If the wildcard expanded to filenames, `ls` will list them on `stdout`; otherwise it will print an error on `stderr`, and nothing on stdout. The contents of `stdout` are assigned to `output`.

`if [ -n "$output" ]` tests whether `$output` contains anything.

Another way to write this would be:

```
if [ $(ls home/edward/bank1/fiche/Test* 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -gt 0 ]
```

Comment: what is the -n stands for?

Comment: `test -n <string>` is true if `<string>` is not empty.

Comment: Using `ls` here won't work correctly if there is more than one matching file. Better to use a glob expression. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why won't it work? We're just testing whether `ls` produced any output or not, we don't check whether it's an actual filename. I've changed the variable name to be less misleading.

Comment: Ahh -- I read it as `[ -e "$output" ]`, not `-n`. Yes, that'll work... though it's unnecessarily inefficient. Why use an external tool (called in a subshell!) that generates sorted, formatted output for human consumption when you only want to know if a file exists? You can record the output of a glob expression in an array with no fork at all -- and the shell _has_ to run that glob expression to build the argument list for `ls`, so it's a strict subset of the overhead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know, ruakh's answer demonstrates that method. I didn't think of that method when I wrote my answer.